# https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/photos?access_token=xxxxxx returning error

Tags: java, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to get posts of specific Facebook brand page using following curl command

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/photos?access_token=xxx

Getting following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "DH1T17dMqR+"
  }
}
```

I have used following curl command to get active access token https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY

Facebook app have been created by page admin and client ID & client secret used to get app access token.

Earlier we are using page-id instead of "me" identifier to get the post using above curl and it was working fine for specific facebook account.

Where page-id is id of specific facebook page whose post you want to get.

Now, same configuration is not working for other page.

Comment: You created an app access token here - `/me` does not work with an app access token.

Answer (score 1):

The page is most likely restricted by age or location, so you have to use a User Token or Page Token for `/page-id/photos`.

More information about Tokens:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/